# The contents of the file are written to the queue and count the number of vowels

Tags: c++

I need to write two functions:

- 1 function) It is necessary to read from the file and write words to the queue.
- 2 function) you need to calculate how many vowels in each recorded in the queue word.

I throw off everything I could do. I need your help:

1. Did I make the first function right?(5  elements)
2. Did I do the right thing 3?
3. Do I correctly output to main?

At me for a while anything on 
screen why that is not deduced (((

```
std::queue<std::string> queue;
std::string str;
void ProduceData()
{
    const std::string& pathToFile = "D:\\text.txt";
    unsigned number = 5;
    std::ifstream stream(pathToFile);
    if (!stream)
    {
        std::cout << "Can not open file" << "\n";
    }
    while (stream >> str)
    {
        for (size_t index = 0; index < number; ++index)
        {
            stream >> str;
            queue.push(str);
        }
    }
}

bool isVowel(const char ch)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
       case 'A':
       case 'a':
       case 'E':
       case 'e':
       case 'I':
       case 'i':
       case 'O':
       case 'o':
       case 'U':
       case 'u':
         return true;
       default:
        return false;
  }
}
void ConsumeData()
{
    while (!queue.empty())
    {
       const std::string& str = queue.front();
       std::size_t numVowels = std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isVowel);
        std::cout << str << ": " << numVowels;
        queue.pop();
    }
}


int main()
{
  ConsumeData();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's totally unclear what you're asking. 1. What are you saying that you only want to evaluate the first 5 words? 2. I'm unclear if you're totalling the vowels, counting the vowels per word, or some other wacky idea. 3. You don't output to main at all, you're printing in `ConsumeData`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this, cause I never have the opportunity to use [`istreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator). To find the total number of vowels, given a valid `ifstream input`, you can do:

```
count_if(istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), istreambuf_iterator<char>(), [](const auto i) { return i == 'A' || i == 'a' || i == 'E' || i == 'e' || i == 'I' || i == 'i' || i == 'O' || i == 'o' || i == 'U' || i == 'u'; } )
```

To find and output the vowel count per-word you can use the `count_if` with an [`istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator):

```
auto count = 0;

for(auto i = istream_iterator<string>(input); i != istream_iterator<string>(); ++i) {
    cout << ++count << ": " << count_if(cbegin(*i), cend(*i), [](const auto i) { return i == 'A' || i == 'a' || i == 'E' || i == 'e' || i == 'I' || i == 'i' || i == 'O' || i == 'o' || i == 'U' || i == 'u'; } ) << endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/BIvwgp)

Answer (score 0):

I have commented the method you are using to calculate the number of vowel as you have sent `isVowel` as function parameter to it, is not clear how that method body is using your function `isVowel`. Rather use below codes which is more clear for your.

```
while (!queue.empty())
{
   const std::string& str = queue.front();
   //std::size_t numVowels = std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isVowel);
       std::size_t numVowels = 0;
   int i = 0;
   while(i < str.length())
   {
      if(isVowel(str[i++]))
         numVowels++            
   }
   std::cout << str << ": " << numVowels;
   queue.pop();
}
```

change the code as below and try

```
while (!queue.empty())
{
   const std::string& str =  queue.pop();//queue.front();
   //std::size_t numVowels = std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isVowel);
   std::size_t numVowels = 0;
   int i = 0;
  while(i < str.length())
  {
      if(isVowel(str[i++]))
      numVowels++            
   }
   std::cout << str << ": " << numVowels;
   //queue.pop();
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing? just add `std::cout << str << ": " << numVowels;` line just above the inner `while` loop and check whether your queue is working properly or not

Comment: @ Abhijit 
I count only the first word and do not translate into another word in the queue. you are in the same queue you do the same. how to switch to another word? And then I'll only bring out the loud first words many times (((

Comment: Hi, See my answer. I have modified the code below try with that.